# Is there a shorter way to show a data in a Firebase Database with textView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple responsibility, I want to learn something.
How can I show the data in Firebase Database with TextView?

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyData");

    mDatabase.child("Dog").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String txt = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Splash_Title.setText(txt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I can show it with this method, but I want to know if there is a shorter way.

I want to get the value of the TextView with the data "Dog"
Thanks in advance.

`{
  "MyData" : {
    "Cat" : "x",
    "Dog" : "y"
  }
}`

Comment: Your code looks pretty optimal for reading a single value from the database and putting it in a text view. Fun fact: your code registers a permanent listener, meaning that changes in your database will also be updated in your app/text view. Try it! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, dear, I will try again and again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As frank says, what you are doing is correct, since you are pointing out to just 1 value inside MyData node. This can be great if you only need to get that only value, but if you want to get all the values from the MyData object you should write a POJO class, and then get the values with a foreach, this will bring out to you all the values from MyData

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyData");

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DatasnapShot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            MyData md = snapShot.getValue(MyData.class);
            String dog = md.getDog(); //get dog name
            String cat = md.getCat(); // get cat name
            //And then just do a log to print or see those values
            Log.e("DogAndCatName",""+dog+cat);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and you will only need another class that is your POJO named `MyData.class`

with this we are creating the object MyData to access each data from that object in your dataSnapshot request.

```
  public class MyData {

    private String Dog;
    private String Cat;

    public MyData() {
    }

    public String getDog() {
        return Dog;
    }

    public void setDog(String dog) {
        Dog = dog;
    }

    public String getCat() {
        return Cat;
    }

    public void setCat(String cat) {
        Cat = cat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes. The answer I'm looking for is thank you very much dear. I applied a similar method. I created a model and called it with Get but could not get it working. I want to show the same data in My Data as you say. It will work. Happy codes and thanks dear.

Comment: Hi Gaston. As much as possible, we try to encourage a technical standard of writing here. It can generally be assumed that people answering questions do indeed hope that their post helps, and indeed it is to be hoped that readers are all happy coders, but we don't need 24.6 million instances of these phrases on the site. Would you refrain from adding these in the future, please? They will get edited out eventually.

Comment: Halfer, thanks for the advice ! Will do in further answers .